# Flow control with Promise

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, bluebird

I have this piece of code:

```
var totalAmount = 0;

Returns.find().populate("products")
    .then(function (returns){
        return returns;
    })

    .each(function (returns){
        ReturnsService.getTotalAmount(returns.products, function(err, result){
            totalAmount = totalAmount + result;
        });
    })

    .then(function (){
        return res.send({total : totalAmount});
    });
```

Why is the result of this code is 0, it's like the each is not being finished before the last then is being fired?

Comment: Are you sure 'each' is a method returned by your promise library?

Comment: Also, is ReturnsService.getTotalAmount asynchronous?

Comment: What is the output of each `result` ? Are they all positive numbers?

Comment: @TravisWebb Yes it's returning positive numbers.

Comment: @BryceJohnson Yes I'm using callback for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ReturnsService.getTotalAmount()` is asynchronous, Bluebird's [`.each()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise) won't wait for that to complete its work and for `totalAmount` to be modified without some guidance:

> If the iterator function returns a promise or a thenable, then the result of the promise is awaited, before continuing with next iteration.

If `getTotalAmount()` provides a promise itself, a `return` is all that needs to be added:

```
.each(function (returns){
    return ReturnsService.getTotalAmount(returns.products, ...);
})
```

Otherwise, a [`new Promise()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#new-promisefunctionfunction-resolve-function-reject-resolver---promise) should be created for it:

```
.each(function (returns) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ReturnsService.getTotalAmount(returns.products, function(err, result){
            if (err)
                return reject(err);

            totalAmount = totalAmount + result;
            resolve(totalAmount);
        });
    });
})
```

---

As as aside, the scenario of iterating to determine a single value (sum total, etc.) is the intent of another method -- [`.reduce()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#reducefunction-reducer--dynamic-initialvalue---promise).

```
.reduce(function (runningTotal, returns) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ReturnsService.getTotalAmount(returns.products, function(err, result){
            if (err)
                return reject(err);

            resolve(runningTotal + result); // resolve with new total
        });
    });
}, 0 /* initial value */)

// combined total will be passed as the argument
.then(function (totalAmount) {
    return res.send({ total : totalAmount });
});
```

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - `resolve(totalAmount)` - as you need that value later

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski `totalAmount` is defined in an outer scope, allowing it be reached without passing it along. It can certainly be useful to pass it, but just isn't required in this case.